# How do you install a new build controller in TFS?

Tags: team-foundation-server

I am not looking for detailed instructions, I just want the quick and dirty overview.

We have an existing TFS infrastructure, I am looking to install a new build controller for 1 team project.

Do I need to create a new VM and install TFS (configure as controller) and then link it from the VM to the main TFS instance?

OR

Do I need to create the new VM, install TFS (configure as controller) and then - From the main TFS admin console on the main TFS server - add the new controller?

Thanks in advance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're okay with running the controller on the tfs at, you would just use the tfs admin tool to add it, a build agent, and then you're set. If you need more CPU/disk for builds, you might use a different physical box (metal or vm). When you set up the controller wherever it is, you link it to a collection. You'll need collection admin rights to do this. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

You do everything from the VM where you installed the TFS bits. Make sure port 9191 is open in addition to 8080. If the machines belongs to the same domain, it is child's play.